# How can I validate with javascript and then submit data with php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, onclick

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

When I press this button it runs a javascript validation function that returns true or false based on whether some data is formatted properly.

What I need to do next is: if true submit the validated data to mySql database using a php script.

I am stumped at how I can accomplish this. I hope I am clear. Thanks.

Also, I can't use ajax.

Comment: Are you allowed to use jquery library?

Comment: No, just suppose to use javascript, php, and html & css.

Answer (score 3):

In the php file you can do all the mysql verifications needed.
The submit  can be something like this

```
<form action="update.php" method="post"> <button type="submit" onclick="return submitForm()">Submit</button> </form>
```

Notice the return in the function call.
The verification is returning false when validation fails.

```
function submitForm() {  
   if(validation) { // fails    
      alert("your message");  
      return false; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do your button type to submit and send to the form ex like this

`<form action="update.php" method="post">`
`<button type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>`
`</form>`

In index.php file check the mysql validation

You have missed the return in the function call. Try with

`<button type="button" onclick="return submitForm()">Submit</button>`

where you are returning false when validation fails.

`function submitForm() {`
 `if(validation) // fails`
  `{`
  `alert("your message");`
  `return false;`
 `}`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

use `type = "submit"` instead of `button`. try with -

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

js validation

```
function submitForm() {
   //your validation codes

   //if validates

       return true
   //else

       return false;
}
```

if validation succeeds the the form will be submitted else will not be submitted.

Comment: Submitted to what? another function? Is that other function in the form tag?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
function submitForm() {
  if(){ //condition to validate
    return true;
  }else{
    return false; 
  }
```

}

Also (as a suggestion) you can add a specific function to validate each type of value so then just call it in your function `submitForm()` by those types

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `return` in the function call. Try with

```
<button type="button" onclick="return submitForm()">Submit</button>
                                 ^
```

where you are returning `false` when validation fails.

```
function submitForm() {
   if(validation) // fails
  {
   alert("your message");
   return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your button type to submit and send to the form
ex like this

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
....
<button type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In index.php file check the mysql validation

Hope this will help you

Comment: So the submitForm() function is javascript? and if it is, when the submitForm() returns true index.php will run? do i need the return keyword?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add more detail from your html page. For instance the html form itself.

However just a hunch of what you are looking for.... you can use the folling command in your submitForm() function:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Comment: this should be a comment. not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

We can't much help if we don't see your code. But in a nutshell you would submit the form by

```
document.getElementById('formId').submit();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("form").submit()
```

Answer (score -1):

What I need to do next is:

1->perform form.submit()

2->send all data's to database from your action file (action="action.php")

Comment: *"What I need to do next is"*.. what..? is this an answer or a *note to self* ..?

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function formValidator(){
        // Make quick references to our fields
        var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
        var addr = document.getElementById('addr');
        var zip = document.getElementById('zip');
        var state = document.getElementById('state');
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        var email = document.getElementById('email');

        // Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
        if(isAlphabet(firstname, "Please enter only letters for your name")){
            if(isAlphanumeric(addr, "Numbers and Letters Only for Address")){
                if(isNumeric(zip, "Please enter a valid zip code")){
                    if(madeSelection(state, "Please Choose a State")){
                        if(lengthRestriction(username, 6, 8)){
                            if(emailValidator(email, "Please enter a valid email address")){
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return false;

    }

    function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
        if(elem.value.length == 0){
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function isNumeric(elem, helperMsg){
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function isAlphabet(elem, helperMsg){
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
        var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function lengthRestriction(elem, min, max){
        var uInput = elem.value;
        if(uInput.length >= min && uInput.length <= max){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert("Please enter between " +min+ " and " +max+ " characters");
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function madeSelection(elem, helperMsg){
        if(elem.value == "Please Choose"){
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    function emailValidator(elem, helperMsg){
        var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
        if(elem.value.match(emailExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>

    <form onsubmit='return formValidator()' >
    First Name: <input type='text' id='firstname' /><br />
    Address: <input type='text' id='addr' /><br />
    Zip Code: <input type='text' id='zip' /><br />
    State: <select id='state'>
        <option>Please Choose</option>
        <option>AL</option>
        <option>CA</option>
        <option>TX</option>
        <option>WI</option>
    </select><br />
    Username(6-8 characters): <input type='text' id='username' /><br />
    Email: <input type='text' id='email' /><br />
    <input type='submit' value='Check Form' />
    </form>
```

Comment: *copy and paste this in a text editor* isn't encouraged answering format in SO as far as i know..

Comment: is there somthing wrong with the code ? i think it is well illustrated rather than giving directions

Comment: please let me know so that i will make it better next time

Comment: Where did this code came from..? what does it do..? How do you know what are the validations OP requires..? where is the part that "*submit the validated data to mySql database using a php script"*..?. This isn't an answer for the question. This is a code dump based on assumptions.